# Not being allowed to use some terms in Add New Site in Wordpress

Tags: multisite, blog, subdomains

The following words are reserved for use by WordPress functions and cannot be used as blog names: page, comments, blog, files, feed

This is the error message that I'm getting. I wanted to use /blog as a sub-site in the network. What I require is that my site has the following structure:

```
Home (only contains links to the other parts)
Part 1
Part 2
Blog
```

Would using permalinks solve my problem? I want all my blogs to appear in only the 'Blog' part of the site and nowhere else.

Another follow-up query is that, since I'm working on this site on my localhost, I'm using sub-folders. But when I eventually transfer the site on a web host, I want to use sub-domains. I'm mentioning this as I fear that any solution to the above problem can influence this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Permalinks

/blog cannot be used as a new site name. It is relied on heavily by WP for the main site. Everything added to it automatically has /blog as part of the permalink from my understanding

You can check out this discussion
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/root-directory-blog-for-wordpress-30-main-multisite
to see if it helps you out, gives some further options.

The main issue with the /blog is to prevent collisions. I'm not sure of the repercussions of not using it, when using subdomains

I'm not sure if you can easily switch from subfolders to subdomains..... I would think that would cause some issues. I think when you transfer over, the existing subsites are not switched.... so if you set it up one way, and try to change, there may be some headaches